# Missing ttkstub.lib when linking

Tags: tcl, ttk

I am trying to port a very old legacy project, trying to get it to compile right now. Project is a mix of C/C++ and tcl. During linking stage in Visual Studio (2010) I get an error that linker was not able to find `ttkstub.lib`

Project relies on some version of tcl 8.5. I could not find any mention of `ttkstub.lib` anywhere online nor does it seem to come with any tcl distribution.

Linker seems to be expecting to find this library in Tcl installation folder in "lib/" directory.

Given that interwebs do not mention `ttkstub.lib` file, chances are it may be something custom, but thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: The ttk library got integrated into Tk itself back in 8.5; it was originally a separate project so that it could be developed more rapidly. `ttkstub.lib` will have been the stub library for it.

Comment: @DonalFellows what would be the best way of obtaining this stub library? It looks like tcl releases before 8.5 require building from source?

Comment: You don't need it anymore with Tk 8.5+. Just link against `tkstub.lib` and remove `ttkstub.lib` from the linker command.